# Remove reduntant space between subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot dates on the x axis and I do not really understand the relationship between margin,width of bars. I want to have bars that are close to each other and separated by a small gap between each unique date(bar). Each time I draw my graph I notice I get other dates which are not stipulated in my code. How can I clean up my code to have the bars close to each other with a reasonable spacing and remove the dates that do not have any data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

x = [datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 10, 0),
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 10, 0),
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 9, 0),
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 5, 9, 0)]

y = [5,4, 9, 2]

ax = plt.subplot(111)
colors = ['r','g','b','y']
ax.bar(x, y, width=10,align='center',color=colors,edgecolor = "none")
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

The result I get is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you pass to the `.bar()` function in matplotlib, `x` is not the axis labels, but rather the range of values. So matplotlib automatically tries to make the range of the x-axis to scale. If you instead only want to display YOUR dates, you want to do something like this:

```
dummy_x = range(len(x))
ax.bar(dummy_x, y, width=10,align='center',color=colors,edgecolor = "none")
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
```

To get the formatting right on the labels, you might want to do some additional formatting, something like:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([dt.strftime("%b %Y") for dt in x])
```

Be aware that doing this on your graph means that the x-axis ticks no longer represent the same distances between the bars - it all depends on what you want to show, but it might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `x` that you want and then pass the labels with `tick_label`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 0, 2, 1]
y = [5,4, 9, 2]

labels = ['Dec 2010', 'Dec 2010', 'Jan 2011', 'May 2011']

ax = plt.subplot(111)
colors = ['r','g','b','y']
ax.bar(x, y,align='center',color=colors,edgecolor = "none",
   tick_label=labels)

plt.show()
```